# Merge sort implementation in JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, mergesort

Just for learning and practicing I've created a completely recursive version of the merge sort algorithm.

I've tested it a little bit and it seems working, but I'm quite sure that it can be largely improved. In particular, I'm hating the long `if`-`else` conditional inside the sort function. I think it's really bad written but I can't figure out a way to "beautify" the code without using a loop.

```
function merge(left, right, array){
    if (left.length == 0 && right.length == 0) {
        return array;
    } else if (left.length == 0) {
        return array.concat(right);
    } else if (right.length == 0) {
        return array.concat(left);
    } else if (left[0] < right[0]) {
        array.push(left.shift());
    } else if (left[0] > right[0]) {
        array.push(right.shift());
    } else {
        array.push(left.shift());
        right.shift();
    }
    return merge(left, right, array);
}

function mergeSort(array){
    if (array.length > 1) {
        return merge(mergeSort(array.slice(0, Math.ceil(array.length/2))),
            mergeSort(array.slice(Math.ceil(array.length/2))), []);
    } else {
        return array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `mergeSort([2, 1, 5])` -> `[1, 1, 2, 5]` ?

You have a bug:

> ```
> > mergeSort([2, 1, 5]);
> [1, 1, 2, 5]
>
> > mergeSort([2, 1, 5, 1, 9]);
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 9]
> ```

The problem is here:

> ```
> sort(mergeSort(array.slice(0, Math.ceil(array.length/2))),
>             mergeSort(array.slice(Math.floor(array.length/2, array.length))), []);
> ```

For example for the array `[1, 2, 3]`,
the first slice will be `[1, 2]` and the second will be `[2, 3]`,
so `2` gets duplicated.
The more ranges you have with odd length,
the more duplicates will creep in.

I'm also wondering what was the intention of this:

> ```
> Math.floor(array.length/2, array.length)
>                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^  typo?
> ```

It seems that changing the slices to this will fix it:

```
array.slice(0, Math.ceil(array.length / 2)))
array.slice(Math.ceil(array.length / 2), array.length))
```

#### Naming

The `sort` method doesn't "sort".
It merges.
As such, I'd rename it to `merge`.

#### Beauty

> i think it's really bad written but i can't figure out a way to "beautify" the code without using a loop

I think it's fine.
This is clear, easy to read, not really ugly.
But I'd use spaces more generously around parentheses, like this:

```
function merge(left, right, array){
    if (left.length == 0 && right.length == 0) {
        return array;
    } else if (left.length == 0) {
        return array.concat(right);
    } else if (right.length == 0) {
        return array.concat(left);
    } else if (left[0] < right[0]) {
        array.push(left.shift());
    } else {
        array.push(right.shift());
    }
    return merge(left, right, array);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @janos! The Math.floor was an error that i've had already fixed but then i shared the wrong version, my fault :). About the bug when inside the array there are duplicates... That's something i forgot to handle, i'll fix it right now!